# Iterative Optimization in GAMS

Tags: optimization, gams-math

Assuming a single farm problem as in the case of Mayaland example (`Hazell & Norton, 1986; Chapter 2; section 2.2`), we can use the following code for optimization in `GAMS`.

**Data (Single farm)**

- **Mayaland.csv**

```
resrs,Corn,    Bean,  Sorghum,  Peanut
Land,1,1,1,1
Labor,1.42,1.87,1.92,2.64
Mules,1.45,1.27,1.16,1.45
Market,,,,0.98
```

- **ressourses_endowments.csv**

```
resrs,resEndow
Labor,16.5
Land,5
Mules,10
Market,0.5
```

- **activity_gross_margin.csv**

```
crop,grosMarg
Corn,1372
Bean,1219
Sorghum,1523
Peanut,4874
```

**Code (single farm)**

```
SETS resrs, crops;

PARAMETERS
    farmData
    resEndow
    grosMarg
    ;

************************** I prefer NOT to input data like this **************************
*SETS
*    resrs ressourses /labor, land, mules, market /
*    crops mayaland activities /
*Corn
*Bean
*Sorghum
*Peanut
*/
*;
*PARAMETERS
*
*resEndow (resrs) ressourses endowments
*                        /
*                        Labor 16.5
*                        Land 5
*                        Mules 10.0
*                        Market 0.5
*                        /
*grosMarg (crops) gross margins
*                        /
*                        Corn 1372
*                        Bean 1219
*                        Sorghum 1523
*                        Peanut 4874
*                        /
*;
*table farmData A ressource requirements
*         Corn    Bean  Sorghum  Peanut
*Land     1       1      1       1
*Labor    1.42    1.87   1.92    2.64
*Mules    1.45    1.27   1.16    1.45
*Market                          0.983
*;
*
*******************************************************************************************

******************** I prefer to load the data from csv files like this********************
$call csv2gdx Mayaland.csv id=farmData useHeader=y fieldSep=Comma index=1 values=2..lastCol trace=3 
$ifE errorLevel<>0 $abort Problems reading Mayaland.csv!

$gdxIn Mayaland.gdx
$load resrs             = dim1
$load crops            = dim2
$load farmData
$gdxIn
;

$call csv2gdx ressourses_endowments.csv id=resEndow useHeader=y fieldSep=Comma index=1 values=2 trace=3 
$ifE errorLevel<>0 $abort Problems reading ressourses_endowments.csv!

$gdxIn ressourses_endowments.gdx
$load resEndow
$gdxIn
;

$call csv2gdx activity_gross_margin.csv id=grosMarg useHeader=y fieldSep=Comma index=1 values=2 trace=3 
$ifE errorLevel<>0 $abort Problems reading activity_gross_margin.csv!

$gdxIn activity_gross_margin.gdx
$load grosMarg
$gdxIn
;
*******************************************************************************************


DISPLAY resEndow, grosMarg, farmData;

VARIABLES

Prft Total gross margin
x(crops) activity levels
;

EQUATIONS

Profit definition of Z
RESCON ressouse constraint
NONNEG non-negativity condition;

Profit.. Prft =E= sum(crops, grosMarg (crops)*x(crops));
RESCON(resrs).. sum(crops, farmData(resrs, crops)*x(crops)) =L= resEndow(resrs);
NONNEG(crops).. x(crops) =G= 0;

model mayaland / Profit, RESCON, NONNEG /
;

SOLVE mayaland maximizing Prft using LP;
DISPLAY x.l, Prft.l;
```

Now, I would like to add several nested levels and solve the problem for each unique combination of these levels. Consider we have several farmers from different regions with different type of farming practices as in the following data

**Data (Multiple farms, Multiple regions, Multiple farming practices)**

- **Mayaland.csv**

```
farmer,region,practice,resrs,Corn,    Bean,  Sorghum,  Peanut
farmer1,a,p1,Land,1,1,1,1
farmer1,a,p1,Labor,1.42,1.87,1.92,2.64
farmer1,a,p1,Mules,1.45,1.27,1.16,1.45
farmer1,a,p1,Market,,,,0.98
farmer2,b,p2,Land,1,1,1,1
farmer2,b,p3,Labor,1.42,1.87,1.92,2.64
farmer2,b,p4,Mules,1.45,1.27,1.16,1.45
farmer2,b,p5,Market,,,,0.98
```

- **ressourses_endowments.csv**

```
farmer,region,practice,resrs,resEndow
farmer1,a,p1,Land,16.5
farmer1,a,p1,Labor,5
farmer1,a,p1,Mules,10
farmer1,a,p1,Market,0.5
farmer2,b,p2,Land,16.5
farmer2,b,p3,Labor,5
farmer2,b,p4,Mules,10
farmer2,b,p5,Market,0.5
```

- **activity_gross_margin.csv**

```
farmer,region,practice,crop,grosMarg
farmer1,a,p1,Corn,1372
farmer1,a,p1,Bean,1219
farmer1,a,p1,Sorghum,1523
farmer1,a,p1,Peanut,4874
farmer2,b,p2,Corn,1372
farmer2,b,p3,Bean,1219
farmer2,b,p4,Sorghum,1523
farmer2,b,p5,Peanut,4874
```

**Expected result (Multiple farms, Multiple regions, Multiple farming practices)**

How can we make the above code work for solving the problem for each unique combination of multiple levels? In other words, each row in `Mayaland.csv` (below) represents an independent observation, hence should be modelled independently.

```
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 1
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 2
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 3
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 4
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 5
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 6
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 7
farmer,region,practice   ===================================>  result 8
```

**Reference**

Hazell, P. B. R., & Norton, R. D. (1986). *Mathematical programming for economic analysis in agriculture*. New York, US. https://www.ifpri.org/publication/mathematical-programming-economic-analysis-agriculture

Answer (score 2):

1. Form a set `frp(farmer,region,practice)` with allowed combinations. This can be read from the csv file or calculated from e.g. gross margin.
2. Loop over this set

   ```
   parameter results(farmer,region,practice,*,*) 'collect results'; 
   loop(frp(farmer,region,practice),
   * extract data for single case
          endow(res) =  endowmentData(farmer,region,practice,res);
          ...
   * solve single case
          solve ....
   * store results in parameter
          results(farmer,region,practice,'x',crops) = x.l(crops);
          results(farmer,region,practice,'profit','-') = Prft.l;
          ....
   );
   * export results to spreadsheet or csv file.
   ```

PS It may be easier to use a single spreadsheet with all data compared to multiple csv files.

Comment: Hi @Erwin Kalvelagen, thanks for helping! I couldn't set up the equations the right way. Brief,  I can't seem to translate your explanation into actual code that works. Would you mind updating your answer to provide a more complete solution?  I will share the single CSV file of the data in the next comment.

Comment: `farmer,region,practice,resrs,crop,Corn,    Bean,  Sorghum,  Peanut,resEndow,grosMarg
farmer1,a,p1,Land,Corn,1,1,1,1,16.5,1372
farmer1,a,p1,Labor,Bean,1.42,1.87,1.92,2.64,5,1219
farmer1,a,p1,Mules,Sorghum,1.45,1.27,1.16,1.45,10,1523
farmer1,a,p1,Market,Peanut,,,,0.98,0.5,4874
farmer2,b,p2,Land,Corn,1,1,1,1,16.5,1372
farmer2,b,p3,Labor,Bean,1.42,1.87,1.92,2.64,5,1219
farmer2,b,p4,Mules,Sorghum,1.45,1.27,1.16,1.45,10,1523
farmer2,b,p5,Market,Peanut,,,,0.98,0.5,4874`

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Model equations should be identical to your "single case" model.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand much. The equations do not work if I changed the data. Right from `Profit.. Prft =E= sum(crops, grosMarg (crops)*x(crops))`, I get the error `dimension different - the symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared`. Does this works in your end?

Comment: True, the error message is self-explanatory, yet I can't seem to understand how to solve it. It would help me quite substantially, if you can update your answer.